# mysql trigger one to many relation

Tags: mysql, triggers

So i have 3 tables Production, Stop_Prodcution and triggered_table.
production has a one to many realation with Stop_prodcution where a production can have a lot of stop prodcutions.

```
 production table 
-----------------------
  id_prod |   date
-----------------------
    1     |20/03/2019
    2     |18/04/2019

 Stop_Production table
  ----------------------------
 id_stop |    name    | id_prod
  ----------------------------
    1    | Any reason |    1
    2    |   Lunch    |    1
    3    |damaged prod|    2

 triggered_table
 ----------------------------
 id|id_prod|date|id_stop|name
```

*i've created 2 triggers:*

```
after insert into production         
for each row         
insert into triggered_table        
(id_prod,date) values (new.id_prod, curdate())
```

*and the other one:*

```
after update     
set id_stop=new.id_stop, 
name= new.name     
where id_prod= new.id_prod
```

the problem is that a production record is able to have 2 or more stop_Production records so with the triggers that I have, it will update always the same record, but what I need is a new record with same information of production table and the information that differs from the new inserted row in stop_production, please tell me if I explained my self if not I'll try to be more clear.

Comment: why do you need `triggered_table`?  You can simply `JOIN` the `production` table and the `stop_production` table.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the results you want, without using a trigger:

```
SELECT 
t1.id_stop,
t1.id_prod,
t1.`name`,
t2.date
FROM stop_production
LEFT JOIN production
ON (t1.id_prod = t2.id);
```

If you want to make a "table" out of this, you can create a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html).

```
CREATE VIEW triggered_table AS (
    SELECT 
    t1.id_stop,
    t1.id_prod,
    t1.`name`,
    t2.date
    FROM stop_production
    LEFT JOIN production
    ON (t1.id_prod = t2.id)
)
```

Then, if you want to `SELECT`from this "table", you can simply:

```
SELECT * FROM triggered_table;
```